# UpdateButton_Click in form view

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I Have a page(manage-darkhast-maghale.aspx) that include a gridview and sqldatasourse.one of the gridview columns is a hyperlink that on click redirects users to (pasokhmaghale.aspx?darkhastMaghaleId={0})
in second page there is a formview and sqldatasourse. after double click on update button on edit template on code behind I have typed below codes to redirect user to first page.

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("manage-darkhast-maghale.aspx");
    }
```

but, after running site and clicking on update button only the page begin redirect and the data has no change on gridview and database. anyone can help me please?

Comment: Are the values actually getting saved to the database? Show your ASPX and code-behind markup so we can see what the problem is!

Comment: you now, I do this work only with asp.net wizard, and before adding updatebutton click there was no error and data saved in datasbase, but after adding that response.redirect code all the thing is wrong. I have no other code in code behind @Seany84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code it is very hard to say. From the information you have provided I would say that you need to leave the `CommandName` attribute on your `Update` button in the `EditItemTemplate` i.e.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
```

I would add the following event to your `FormView` that will execute when the record has been updated:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"...
```

In your code behind for the FormView you should have the following:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception == null && e.AffectedRows > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("manage-darkhast-maghale.aspx");
    }
}
```